# Take overlapping properties of struct A and fillup same values in struct B

Tags: go, struct, type-conversion

one of the anoying parts in go is everytime this damn manually conversion from struct type to struct type.

for examople i have this two struct types:

```
type BasketItem struct {
  ProductId int
  Quantity int
  Price float64
  Tax float64
  BasketId int
  UserId int
}

type BillingItem struct {
      ProductId int
      Quantity int
      Price float64
      Tax float64
      BillingId int
      UserId int
      CustomerGroup int
      CreationDate int
      OtherFieldsThatIDontWannaHaveInStructA string
    }
```

So now if i have a BasketItem with values then i wanna now create just a BillingItem with the same values prefiled like:

```
basketItem := BasketItem{ProductId:5,Quantity:5,Price:4.50,UserId:0, BasketId:10}
billingItem := BillingItem{basketItem}
print(billingItem.Price) // should be 4.50
```

I now i can make a structs that have all the overlapping properties and then extend the other two structs from that but honestly this is not a real world example and therefor is not a good solution for me. it interessets me how this generally work with two totally different structs from different modules but some overlaping (same named) properties.

For Example Gorm also in the Response just fill up the matched fields of a struct and skip the others...

Comment: You can't do that. You could write a helper function that uses reflection that copies fields with matching names, but that's all. It will be always slower than manually copying the fields.

Comment: All in all, if the matching fields store logically identical properties and you need to copy them, they should be moved to a separate struct and use them when it's appropriate.

Comment: is there any workauround over convert to json, map, array and back?

Comment: The workaround is in my first comment: write a utility using reflection. To convert to JSON? Use `encoding/json`.

Comment: yes i know reflection but will struct a to jason, json to struct b not fit it simpler and faster? performancelike whats your expirience? my primary gol is not to have much redudant boilerplate code...

Comment: Marshaling to JSON and back will be a lot slower. To begin with, `encoding/json` also uses refleciton, and does a lot of other stuff like generating string and escaping. The reverse process also have to work through that. Implementing field copying using reflection will be a lot faster than using JSON round-trip, and manually assigning fields will also be a lot faster than using reflection.